# How to remove synaptic without installing all the unwanted packages?

Tags: apt, uninstall, synaptic

I am trying to uninstall synaptic. I prefer using apt-get and other command line tools to manage my packages. So I do not need synaptic and the software manager. I'm trying to remove both of them using apt-get.

Its a new box. Recently installed Linux Mint mate 15. After installation, the only thing I did was,

`sudo apt-get update` and
`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

After that, I did this command for removing synaptic,

`sudo apt-get remove --purge synaptic`

But this gives me a very weird output,

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  apturl-kde icoutils kate-data katepart kde-runtime kde-runtime-data kdelibs-bin kdelibs5-data kdelibs5-plugins kdesudo kdoctools kubuntu-debug-installer
  libattica0.4 libdlrestrictions1 libkactivities-bin libkactivities-models1 libkactivities6 libkatepartinterfaces4 libkcmutils4 libkde3support4 libkdeclarative5
  libkdecore5 libkdesu5 libkdeui5 libkdewebkit5 libkdnssd4 libkemoticons4 libkfile4 libkhtml5 libkidletime4 libkio5 libkjsapi4 libkjsembed4 libkmediaplayer4
  libknewstuff3-4 libknotifyconfig4 libkntlm4 libkparts4 libkpty4 libkrosscore4 libktexteditor4 libkxmlrpcclient4 libnepomuk4 libnepomukcore4abi1 libnepomukquery4a
  libnepomukutils4 libntrack-qt4-1 libntrack0 libphonon4 libplasma3 libpolkit-qt-1-1 libpoppler-qt4-4 libqapt2 libqapt2-runtime libqca2 libqt4-qt3support libsolid4
  libsoprano4 libstreamanalyzer0 libstreams0 libthreadweaver4 libvirtodbc0 nepomuk-core nepomuk-core-data ntrack-module-libnl-0 odbcinst odbcinst1debian2
  oxygen-icon-theme phonon phonon-backend-gstreamer plasma-scriptengine-javascript qapt-batch shared-desktop-ontologies soprano-daemon virtuoso-minimal
  virtuoso-opensource-6.1-bin virtuoso-opensource-6.1-common
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  apturl-kde icoutils kate-data katepart kde-runtime kde-runtime-data kdelibs-bin kdelibs5-data kdelibs5-plugins kdesudo kdoctools kubuntu-debug-installer
  libattica0.4 libdlrestrictions1 libkactivities-bin libkactivities-models1 libkactivities6 libkatepartinterfaces4 libkcmutils4 libkde3support4 libkdeclarative5
  libkdecore5 libkdesu5 libkdeui5 libkdewebkit5 libkdnssd4 libkemoticons4 libkfile4 libkhtml5 libkidletime4 libkio5 libkjsapi4 libkjsembed4 libkmediaplayer4
  libknewstuff3-4 libknotifyconfig4 libkntlm4 libkparts4 libkpty4 libkrosscore4 libktexteditor4 libkxmlrpcclient4 libnepomuk4 libnepomukcore4abi1 libnepomukquery4a
  libnepomukutils4 libntrack-qt4-1 libntrack0 libphonon4 libplasma3 libpolkit-qt-1-1 libpoppler-qt4-4 libqapt2 libqapt2-runtime libqca2 libqt4-qt3support libsolid4
  libsoprano4 libstreamanalyzer0 libstreams0 libthreadweaver4 libvirtodbc0 libxml2-utils nepomuk-core nepomuk-core-data ntrack-module-libnl-0 odbcinst
  odbcinst1debian2 oxygen-icon-theme phonon phonon-backend-gstreamer plasma-scriptengine-javascript qapt-batch shared-desktop-ontologies soprano-daemon
  virtuoso-minimal virtuoso-opensource-6.1-bin virtuoso-opensource-6.1-common
Suggested packages:
  libterm-readline-gnu-perl libterm-readline-perl-perl djvulibre-bin finger hspell libqca2-plugin-cyrus-sasl libqca2-plugin-gnupg libqca2-plugin-ossl
  phonon-backend-vlc phonon-backend-xine phonon-backend-mplayer
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  aptoncd* apturl* mintupdate* mintwelcome* synaptic*
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apturl-kde icoutils kate-data katepart kde-runtime kde-runtime-data kdelibs-bin kdelibs5-data kdelibs5-plugins kdesudo kdoctools kubuntu-debug-installer
  libattica0.4 libdlrestrictions1 libkactivities-bin libkactivities-models1 libkactivities6 libkatepartinterfaces4 libkcmutils4 libkde3support4 libkdeclarative5
  libkdecore5 libkdesu5 libkdeui5 libkdewebkit5 libkdnssd4 libkemoticons4 libkfile4 libkhtml5 libkidletime4 libkio5 libkjsapi4 libkjsembed4 libkmediaplayer4
  libknewstuff3-4 libknotifyconfig4 libkntlm4 libkparts4 libkpty4 libkrosscore4 libktexteditor4 libkxmlrpcclient4 libnepomuk4 libnepomukcore4abi1 libnepomukquery4a
  libnepomukutils4 libntrack-qt4-1 libntrack0 libphonon4 libplasma3 libpolkit-qt-1-1 libpoppler-qt4-4 libqapt2 libqapt2-runtime libqca2 libqt4-qt3support libsolid4
  libsoprano4 libstreamanalyzer0 libstreams0 libthreadweaver4 libvirtodbc0 libxml2-utils nepomuk-core nepomuk-core-data ntrack-module-libnl-0 odbcinst
  odbcinst1debian2 oxygen-icon-theme phonon phonon-backend-gstreamer plasma-scriptengine-javascript qapt-batch shared-desktop-ontologies soprano-daemon
  virtuoso-minimal virtuoso-opensource-6.1-bin virtuoso-opensource-6.1-common
0 upgraded, 78 newly installed, 5 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 60.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 146 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? n
Abort.
```

As you can see, apt-get is trying to install the same packages that it is asking me to `autoremove`.

Could someone please tell me, how to uninstall synaptic properly? Or am I missing something?

Just for the record, I also did,
`sudo apt-get autoremove --purge` like it asked me to ... and this is what I got,

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 9):

Try the following commands:

`sudo apt-get remove synaptic*`
`sudo apt-get purge synaptic*`
`sudo apt-get autoremove`
`sudo apt-get autoclean`

Now you are free to go about your life without synaptic.

If you ever think you need it again:

`sudo apt-get install synaptic*`

:)